# C++ std::vector memory/allocation

Tags: c++, memory, stl, vector

From [a previous question about vector capacity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2663170/stdvector-capacity-after-copying), Mr. Bailey said:

> In current C++ you are guaranteed that no reallocation occurs after a call to reserve until an insertion would take the size beyond the value of the previous call to reserve. Before a call to reserve, or after a call to reserve when the size is between the value of the previous call to reserve and the capacity the implementation is allowed to reallocate early if it so chooses.

So, if I understand correctly, in order to assure that no reallocation happens until capacity is exceeded, I must do reserve twice?  Can you please clarify it?

I am using vector as a memory stack like this:

```
std::vector<double> memory;
memory.reserve(size);
memory.insert(memory.end(), matrix.data().begin(), matrix.data().end()); // smaller than size
memory.resize(memory.capacity(), 0);
```

I need to guarantee that reallocation does not happen in the above.

thank you.

ps: I would also like to know if there is a better way to manage memory stack in similar manner other than vector

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're reading the statement wrong. Reserve is allowed to set `capacity` to a larger amount than what you reserved. The special language is to allow an implementation to reallocate if you're reserving more than you did the last time, but before you've reached the current capacity.

Comment: okay, thank you.
I am not English speaker and that sentence was somewhat confusing to me

Comment: @Mark, I don't find this entry to be very clear. 23.3.6.2.2 of C++0X FCD is clearer: Effects: A directive that informs a vector of a planned change in size, so that it can manage the storage
allocation accordingly. After reserve(), capacity() is greater or equal to the argument of reserve if
reallocation happens; and equal to the previous value of capacity() otherwise. Reallocation happens
at this point if and only if the current capacity is less than the argument of reserve(). If an exception
is thrown other than by the move constructor of a non-CopyConstructible type, there are no effects.

Answer (score 0):

It reallocates when it needs more. You don't need to reserve twice. It is a good idea to use reserve if you're doing a lot of inserting and you have good knowledge of the size of what you're storing. It's much faster.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to call `reserve` twice.

Additionally, in the code sample posted, you've only called `reserve` once. In actuality the code you're pasting affects the `size` of the vector. See 23.3.6.2.11 (C++0x FCD) on effects of `void resize(size_type sz, const T& c);`:

```
if (sz > size())
    insert(end(), sz-size(), c);
else if (sz < size())
    erase(begin()+sz, end());
else
     ; // do nothing
```

So, basically, when you call `memory.resize(memory.capacity(), 0)`, you are, in effect, appending on `0`, `memory.capacity() - memory.size()` times following your call to `memory.insert`.

Comment: that is intent.I require some zero memory