# Does a vector assignment invalidate the `reserve`?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

Suppose I write

```
std::vector<T> littleVector(1);
std::vector<T> bigVector;

bigVector.reserve(100);
bigVector = littleVector;
```

Does the standard say that `bigVector` will still have 100 elements reserved? Or would I experience memory reallocation if I were to `push_back` 99 elements? Perhaps it even varies between STL implementations.

This was previously discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2663170/stdvector-capacity-after-copying) but no Standard references were given.

Comment: @davidhigh: yes it would answer the question for my particular compiler and STL implementation but I could also answer questions like "what does `i = i++` do" in a similar way.

Comment: Very nice question, +1. I can't find anything straightforward about it in the standard; something might follow from the dark magic of allocator requirements, though.

Comment: I know it dumps the entire target buffer if the source's allocator is different than the targets. I can't comment on whether it honors current reserve if they utilize the *same* allocator without referring to the standard. (nice question, btw).

Comment: Still it would be nice to know already for your compiler and STL implementation what the result is? If the standard is not immediately clear on it a series of evidences would be the only thing left. Anyway isn't the assignment the same as a copy internally?

Comment: In MSVC it seems to keep the correct reserve unless littleVector has more than 100 objects.

Comment: Have a look at [std::vector resize downward](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1155693/stdvector-resize-downward) which seems to indicate that capacity of a vector never shrinks?

Comment: My compiler (msvc12) keeps the capacity at 100.

Comment: The `g++` implementation explicitly documents that the capacity is __not__ copied; also, `assign` is explicitly requested by the standard to be equivalent to an `erase` followed by an `insert` (which aren't influenced by the source `capacity`). OTOH, I found no place in the standard where `operator=` is mandated to behave in the same way as `assign`.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Unfortunately, the standard underspecifies behavior on allocator-aware sequence container assignment, and indeed is strictly speaking inconsistent.

We know (from Table 28 and from 23.2.1p7) that if `allocator_traits<allocator_type>::propagate_on_container_copy_assignment::value` is `true` then the allocator is replaced on copy assignment. Further, from Tables 96 and 99 we find that the *complexity* of copy assignment is *linear*, and the *post-condition* on operation `a = t` is that `a == t`, i.e. (Table 96) that `distance(a.begin(), a.end()) == distance(t.begin(), t.end()) && equal(a.begin(), a.end(), t.begin())`. From 23.2.1p7, after copy assignment, if the allocator propagates, then `a.get_allocator() == t.get_allocator()`.

With regard to vector capacity, 23.3.6.3 **[vector.capacity]** has:

> 5 - *Remarks:* Reallocation invalidates all the references, pointers, and iterators referring to the elements in the sequence. It is guaranteed that no reallocation takes place during insertions that happen after a call to `reserve()` until the time when an insertion would make the size of the vector greater than the value of `capacity()`.

If we take [library DR341](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/lwg-defects.html#341) as a guide to reading the Standard:

> However, the wording of 23.3.6.3 [vector.capacity]paragraph 5 prevents the capacity of a vector being reduced, following a call to reserve(). This invalidates the idiom, as swap() is thus prevented from reducing the capacity. [...]

DR341 was resolved by adding paragraphs into 23.3.6.3:

> `void swap(vector<T,Allocator>& x);`
>   7 - *Effects:* Exchanges the contents and `capacity()` of `*this` with that of `x`.
>   8 - *Complexity:* Constant time.

The conclusion is that from the point of view of the Library committee, operations only modify `capacity()` if mentioned under 23.3.6.3.  Copy assignment is not mentioned under 23.3.6.3, and thus does not modify `capacity()`.  (Move assignment has the same issue, especially considering the proposed resolution to [Library DR2321](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/lwg-active.html#2321).)

Clearly, this is a defect in the Standard, as copy assignment propagating unequal allocators *must* result in reallocation, contradicting 23.3.6.3p5.

We can expect and hope this defect to be resolved in favour of:

- non-reduced `capacity()` on non-allocator-modifying copy assignment;
- unspecified `capacity()` on allocator-modifying copy assignment;
- non-reduced `capacity()` on non-allocator-propagating move assignment;
- source-container `capacity()` on allocator-propagating move assignment.

However, in the current situation and until this is clarified you would do well not to depend on any particular behavior.  Fortunately, there is a simple workaround that is guaranteed not to reduce `capacity()`:

```
bigVector.assign(littleVector.begin(), littleVector.end());
```

Comment: Capacity remarks restrict the behavior of insertions. Arguably container assignment doesn't fall into the category of insertions.

Comment: @BenVoigt sequence container copy assignment is specified to require `CopyAssignable`. It seems pretty clear that non allocator modifying copy assignment must result in reallocation if initial capacity is insufficient.

Comment: I agree. But I don't know if a pedant would call that operation "insertion" and apply the above rule.

Comment: I've begun a discussion on the ISO C++ forum: https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/forum/#!topic/std-discussion/j6o0qfaUX2c

Answer (score 9):

The only requirement on `operator=` for standard containers is that afterwards, `src == dst`, as specified in Table 96 (in 23.2, General Container Requirements). Furthermore, the same table specifies the meaning of `operator ==`:

```
distance(lhs.begin(), lhs.end()) == distance(rhs.begin(), rhs.end()) // same size
  && equal(lhs.begin(), lhs.end(), rhs.begin()) // element-wise equivalent
```

Note that this doesn't include capacity in any way. Nor does any other part of the standard mention capacity beyond the general invariant that `capacity() >= size()`. The value of capacity after assignment is therefore unspecified, and the container is free to implement assignment whichever way it wants, as long as allocator requirements are kept.

---

In general, you will find that implementations behave such that

- if the allocators compare equal and dst has sufficient capacity, it will retain its old storage,
- otherwise it will allocate just enough storage for the new elements, and
- in no case will care what the capacity of src is.

Of course, move assignment is a different story. Since it is generally implemented by stealing the source storage, the capacity will be taken as well.

Answer (score 6):

This depends on the allocator traits.

Here's an excerpt from http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator%3D:

> If std::allocator_traits::propagate_on_container_copy_assignment() is true, the target allocator is replaced by a copy of the source allocator. If the target and the source allocators do not compare equal, the target (*this) allocator is used to deallocate the memory, then other's allocator is used to allocate it before copying the elements.(since C++11)

Basically, the memory is reallocated with the new allocator, if the allocators are incompatible (if they cannot deallocate each-other's memory.

It shouldn't matter between vector implementations, but between allocator implementations (which makes sense).

Comment: Do you have a normative reference (i.e. from the standard) for that claim?

Comment: While this is correct, it doesn't answer whether deallocation also occurs when the allocators are the same, or do not propagate on container copy assignment.

Comment: @ecatmur: 23.2.1p7 discussed allocator replacement.  The moment of allocator replacement is the last time the container is allowed to use the old allocator for anything; all future operations are defined in terms of the replacement allocator.  Therefore it must deallocate its old buffer at this time.

Comment: @BenVoigt sure, assuming they're unequal.