# How can I allocate memory for the std::vector<std::vector<int> > data type?

Tags: c++, memory-management, vector

Suppose the following data structure `typedef std::vector<std::vector<int> > MYARRAY` is defined. Then for the variable `MYARRAY var`, how can I allocate memory for this variable before pushing data in it. For example,

```
std::vector<int> p1; 
p1.push_back(1);
p1.push_back(2);
std::vector<int> p2;
p2.push_back(22);
p2.push_back(33);
var.push_back(p1);
var.push_back(p2);
```

If we do not allocate memory for `var`, then it will allocate memory automatically. So how can I allocate memory for this var before pushing data insider it? If it is `std::vector<int> var2`, I can just use `var2.reserve(n)` to allocate memory before using it.

**EDIT:**
Two suggestions have been made, but neither can work:

- Solution 1: allocate memory for each element

var.reserve(3);
    for(int i=0; i<3; i++)
        var[i].reserve[20];

I use VC 2010 to compile and run the codes in the debug mode, and the following error message is given:[image]

- Solution 2: create the object in the beginning

  ```
     std::vector<std::vector<int> > var(3, std::vector<int>(5));
  ```

  After you created this variable, you can see this variable in VC 2010:
  [image] 
  Its contents are already there. Therefore, if you push data on this variable, it will allocate memory once again.

**EDIT 2:**

Someone is interested in why I need allocate memory before using this variable， and the main reason is because of run-time library of windows. The variable `var` is defined in a executable program as an empty variable, and its contents are given by a function defined in a dynamic library. If both are using dynamic run-time library, it will not be an issue. But in my case both are linked with static run-time library, which means that each module is in charge of its memory allocation. Since  `var` is defined in the executable program, it also should take care of its memory allocation.

Comment: So what's wrong with `var.reserve(n)`...?

Comment: Why do you need to allocate memory for something that is handled automatically?

Comment: Are you trying to "allocate memory" for each vector element inside MYARRAY?

Comment: @Josh var.rserve(n) will allocate memory for var[0]...var[n], but not for each element for example var[0] itself, it has not allocated memory.

Comment: If this collection is fixed (i.e. cannot be expanded once created) then `std::array` might be a better choice for you.

Comment: @feelfree - Maybe you can tell us *why* you need to do this and not just use `std::vector` as it is?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Thanks for the comments. I edited the question to make it clear why I need to allocate memory for this structure.

Comment: @feelfree - I don't see a "why".  All I see is what you want to do without telling us why you want to do it.  What is the higher-level goal here?  The usage of `vector::reserve` should be self-explanatory, or at least, explained rather well in most online references to `vector`.

Comment: @feelfree Your error in your post is because you've mixed up `reserve` with `resize`.  `reserve` does *not* give you access to the space you've allocated.  You still have to call `push_back`, `insert`, `resize` etc. to fill in the space given to you.  What `reserve` does is to make operations such as `push_back` `resize` and `insert` not need to allocate memory themselves.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you reserve memory for a vector is independent of what type the vector contains. If you want to reserve space for `n` elements in `MYARRAY`, call `MYARRAY.reserve(n);`.

> Its contents are already there. Therefore, if you push data on this variable, it will allocate memory once again.

Right. Do you want to reserve memory or not? If you want to reserve memory, you'll have to use the memory you reserved. In order for you to "push data on this variable", you'd have to have the data somewhere, somewhere other than the memory you reserved. If you reserve memory and use that memory, you'll never have anything to push, because that would imply that you have something someplace other than in the memory you reserved that you need to add to the vector, which you couldn't possibly have.

You basically have three choices:

1) Don't reserve memory. Assemble the objects wherever you want and then push them into the vector. `vec.push_back(myVector);`

2) Reserve memory. Assemble the objects in place in the vector. `vec[n].push_back(myInt);`

3) Reserve memory. Assemble the objects wherever you want and then assign them into the memory you reserved. `vec[n]=myIntVector`

Notice that in none of these cases do you reserve memory and then push into the vector.

Comment: var.rserve(n) will allocate memory for var[0]...var[n], but not for each element for example var[0] itself, it has not allocated memory

Comment: That's correct. If you want to reserve memory for `var[0]`, then call `var[0].reserve`.

Comment: @  David Schwartz I tried with VC 2010, it will intriguer Debug Assertion Failed message.

Comment: @feelfree Show the code that failed. We can't debug code we can't see. (Did you try to reserve space inside an object before creating that object? That can't work.)

Comment: @feelfree See my updates. Your objection doesn't make sense. If you reserved memory, your object would be in the memory you reserved. You wouldn't have some object somewhere else that you need to add to the vector. So you wouldn't be trying to push anything. So your objection that you can't push is invalid.

Answer (score 2):

Like you already pointed out, `std::vector` has the `reserve` method that will reserve space for more data items. If you were to do `p1.reserve(3)` the `vector` would attempt to allocate space for 3 integers. If you run `var.reserve(3)`, `var` will attempt to allocate space for 3 `std::vector<int>`'s, which is what it sounds like you want to do.

To allocate for the `std::vector`'s *inside* of `var`, you could do:

```
for(int x=0; x<var.size(); x++) var[x].reserve(n);
```

## **EDIT**

If you want to allocate space ***before*** inserting the vectors, you can declare `var` as:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int> > var(VEC_COUNT, std::vector<int>(n));
```

And then [copy the new vectors in.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2663170/stdvector-capacity-after-copying)

Comment: thanks, but it will not work as it is illegal to call var[x].reserve(n) as we have not created the element var[x] yet although its memory has been allocated

Comment: thanks, but i do not think it is right. std::vector<std::vector<int> > var(VEC_COUNT, std::vector<int>(n)); will create the object rather than allocate memory for it.

Comment: @feelfree It will create a `vector` with space for `VEC_COUNT` vectors, each with capacity `n`.

Comment: @Josh ... each *of size `n`*. The single-parameter constructor sets the vector's size, not (just) capacity.

Comment: @Angew it doesn't matter what the `size` is here. When he uses the `=` operator to copy in the new vectors, the size will be corrected.

Comment: @feelfree, for the first suggestion, the data must already be in `var`. And for the second, you're going to need to copy the new vectors in with the assignment operator.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot reserve space for vector's data before the vector exists. I believe you're looking for this:

```
void reserve(MYARRAY &arr, size_t dim1, size_t dim2)
{
  arr.resize(dim1);
  for (size_t idx = 0; idx < dim1; ++idx) {
    arr[idx].reserve(dim2);
  }
}
```

Comment: I agree with you and therefore I do not think it is possible to allocate memory for this data structure.