# capacity of vector is 0 when i am inserting it into an un-ordered map

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, unordered-map

I have reserved a vector with size 40 but when i am inserted it into an unordered map as a pair then vector capacity becomes 0.Why is it so?

```
#include<vector> 
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>
using namespace std;

int main() {
   std::vector<int> a;
   a.reserve(40);
   std::cout<<a.capacity()<<std::endl;

   std::unordered_map<int,vector<int>> _map;
   _map.insert(std::make_pair(1,a));
   std::cout<<_map[1].capacity()<<std::endl;



    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Check this out : https://stackoverflow.com/q/37639386/1870232

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `make_pair` will copy construct [(6)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) a new vector, [which does not retain the capacity](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2663170/1332041).

You could also instead force the move constructor [(7)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) which [does retain capacity](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/48ceadc3c6c12066) by using `std::move` but that would be overly complex.

```
_map.insert(std::make_pair(1, std::move(a)));
```

Instead of reserving capacity I'd suggest you simply reserve the size at the point of constructing the vector.

```
std::vector<int> a(40);
```

Answer (score 1):

A copy constructed `std::vector` is not required to preserve the capacity of the object it is copy constructed from. It is only required to preserve the contents.

From https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector:

> Copy constructor. Constructs the container with the copy of the contents of other.